# Does the direction of magnetic field in a solenoid point from north to south anywhere?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

Is there any case where the direction of magnetic field inside a solenoid points from its North Pole to its south?

Comment: Look here  https://www.miniphysics.com/ss-magnetic-field-due-to-current-in-a-solenoid.html

Comment: Yes, on the outside!  South to North inside, North to South outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
It is because field lines travel in closed loops i.e loops don't start or stop at any point, or even cross paths.

This is why field lines are from south to north inside the the solenoid not from north to south.

[image]

Comment: If the field inside the solenoid is from the north to south (marked in pic) then polarity will change ie. the marked north will become the magnetic south and vise-versa